# How to get average/mean of column where night = 1 for example

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, mean

Can someone help me to get the average per night of, for example, the temperature? So I can compare this with another dataframe in which I can see how much sleep someone had.

The picture is how the dataframe looks.

[image]

Comment: Please post your dataframe in your question and not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the time at which it's night. Use them for sunrise and sunset.
Have a function `time_to_float(time)` to calculate the time as the seconds since midnight.

If it is night add the temperature to the sum and increase the number of temperatures by one.

Calculate the sum of the temperatures and divide by the number of temperatures.

```
with open('data.txt' , 'r') as file:
   data= file.read()
   temp_sum=0
   number_temp=0
   for line in data:
       line=line.strip().split(',') #strip the end and split at separator e.g. ,
       time = (line[2].split()[1] # get time without date
       time = time_to_float(time) #write a function to calculate time since 00:00:00
       if (time > sunset or time< sunrise):
           temp-sum+=float(line[3])
           number_temp+=1
   temp_mean=temp_sum/number_temp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can post the dataframe for better comprehension. Using pandas, you can set an index ,then do a groupby the 'Night' column and find
the aggregate mean of the say the Temperature column.

df.groupby('Night')['Temperature'].mean()